# Simple jquery toggle (Not Working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I think I may be using the wrong js library. No idea.. I was following a tutorial online and I saw the guy code it, and watch it work. I reviewed twice and did it over and still didn't work.

Here's my html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="hideshow.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="hideshow">Hide </a>

<div id="message" style="width:300px; border:1px solid black; padding:10px">

This is the wording inside of the text for testing purposes.

</div>
</body>
```

Here's my js from hideshow.js:

```
$('#hideshow').toggle(function () {

$('#hideshow').text('Show');

}, function () {

$('#hideshow').text('Hide');
});
```

I appreciate it, Thanks for whoever can figure this out. :(

Comment: The toggle event was removed from jQuery 1.9. See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're trying to use the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed on jQuery 1.9. The new toggle function has many different overloads, but none that behaves like the old one. [Take a look at it](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and choose the one that suits you the most. For example, you could do something like this:

```
$('#hideshow').click(function () {
    $('#message').toggle();
    if($('#message').is(':visible')) {
        $('#hideshow').text('Hide');        
    } else {
        $('#hideshow').text('Show');   
    }
});
```

And here's a jsfiddle for you to play with. http://jsfiddle.net/74GzV/1/

Comment: I see that, but how could you use this new toggle to also change the text to say "Show"?

Comment: Well... you can't. I updated my answer and the fiddle to show you how you could do it, but the logic for changing the text has nothing to do with the toggle function

Answer (score 0):

As j08691 pointed out, `toggle` is removed, but even if it wasn't `<script src="hideshow.js"></script>` is running before the page has loaded, and therefore `#hideshow` would turn up undefined. Try putting the whole thing in a `$(document).ready` after working around the lack of `toggle`

Answer (score 0):

```
var toggler = $('#hideshow');
toggler.text('Hide');

toggler.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message').slideToggle('slow', function () {
      var togglerLabel = $(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
      toggler.text(togglerLabel);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4TqQT/46/

Comment: And in this one, it changes the text, but after the message has been hidden. I feel like there is an easier way to toggle both the text and hide the message..